# saving state into localstorage in react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I call this function on every button click.

the problem is when the button first clicked it doesn't save the first element until next clicks
so the first element never get saved

```js
 const add=()=>{
    if(website){
      setInfo([...info,{website:website,password:generate()}])
      localStorage.setItem("data",JSON.stringify(info));
    }
  }
```

state info:

```js
const[info,setInfo]=useState([])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInfo` function will update the state asynchronously so when you call `localStorage.setItem` function and pass `info` in it, `info` array hasn't been updated yet.

You can create an array and pass it to `setInfo` and `setItem` function. This way, you don't have to depend on `setInfo` function to update the state before you save it in `localStorage`

```
const add = () => {
   if(website){
      const arr = [...info,{website:website,password:generate()}]
      setInfo(arr);
      localStorage.setItem("data",JSON.stringify(arr));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setInfo` i.e. `setState` is async. You need to use useEffect for this.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(info));
    }, [info]); // run whenever info is changed
```

Every time the state i.e. `info` is changed it will enter the `useEffect` block and update the local storage.

Answer (score 0):

setInfo change will be available on the next render. You should calculate the value in a separate variable and then set it.

```
const add=()=>{
  if(website){
    let value = [...info,{website:website,password:generate()}];
    setInfo(value)
    localStorage.setItem("data",JSON.stringify(value));
  }
}
```